# Lightstreamer Client for Matlab

Tags: matlab, http, post, lightstreamer

I am trying to build a [lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com) client for Matlab. There do exist a couple of libraries for platforms like JAVA, Python, .Net etc. But unfortunately not Matlab.
However, it turns out that most of these client implementations use the very same text-mode protocol for lightstreamer which is pretty basic HTTP requesting.

I figured out how to establish/close a lightstreamer session. I get the sessionId and I can use this id to subscribe to the data I want to stream. But although I do get a valid response for the subscription call, there is no data pushed.

I use the urlead2 function and the response seems fine:

```
 [output,extras]      = urlread2([lightstream_url,'/lightstreamer/control.txt'],'POST',body,headers);
```

allHeaders =

```
      Response: {'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'}
        Server: {'Lightstreamer'}
  Content_Type: {'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1'}
 Cache_Control: {'no-store'  'no-cache'}
        Pragma: {'no-cache'}
       Expires: {'Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'}
          Date: {'Wed, 8 Apr 2015 11:15:02 GMT'}
Content_Length: {'4'}
```

status =

```
value: 200
  msg: 'OK'
```

isGood =

```
 1
```

output =

```
OK
```

It is correct that the response body contains "OK  ", this is documented [(documentation, page 20ff.)](http://www.lightstreamer.com/latest/Lightstreamer_Allegro-Presto-Vivace_4_1_Duomo/Lightstreamer/DOCS-SDKs/sdk_client_generic/doc/Network%20Protocol%20Tutorial.pdf), but there is supposed to be the stream data itself as well, isn't it?

So how do I get the actual data?

Comment: I found out that using the whole URL query in a browser leads to the following lightstream response error: "SYNC ERROR". Maybe this gives a hint?

Comment: right after answering I realized you might already be watching the correct response for the data stream, if so, might it be there is simply no data flowing? Did you ask for a snapshot? Are you in control of the server?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you should have a create_session.txt/bind_session.txt request, otherwise you should not have a valid session id that is required to obtain an OK answer from a control.txt request (e.g. the following generates the SYNC ERROR, that means that the server does not recognize the specified session: http://push.lightstreamer.com/lightstreamer/control.txt?LS_op=add&LS_session=invalid )

The data stream is not received on the control.txt response, that OK response simply means "OK I have added the subscription to your session". 
The data stream is received on the create_session.txt/bind_session.txt response. Sections 4.1 and 4.2 + section 4.5 [on the document you linked](http://www.lightstreamer.com/latest/Lightstreamer_Allegro-Presto-Vivace_4_1_Duomo/Lightstreamer/DOCS-SDKs/sdk_client_generic/doc/Network%20Protocol%20Tutorial.pdf) should explain how the data is received

Comment: The suggestion with the 'bind session' might be the answer. I actually thought it is directly done using control.txt  . The documentation is a bit misleading, I thought it has a similar behaviour as the screen command in unix. I will try out and post the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that opening a polling connection by setting `LS_polling=true` works fine without needing a listner. `urlread2` hangs if you leave `LS_polling` as the default of `false`.

1. Create the session with `/lightstreamer/create_session.txt`
2. Request a subscription with `/lightstreamer/control.txt`
3. Repeatedly poll the connection to get the data with
   `/lightstreamer/bind_session.txt`

The return from `urlread2` will look something like this:

```
d =

OK
SessionId:S9b09da8ebd6b835aT5316913
ControlAddress:apd119a.marketdatasystems.com
KeepaliveMillis:1000
MaxBandwidth:0.0
RequestLimit:50000

1,1|10162.00|0.00|0.00
2,2|10686.8|TRADEABLE|0.5524861
2,13|1202.6|CLOSED|0.5714285
2,14|5900.51|CLOSED|0.5714285
...

LOOP 1000
```